# Flask returning query

Tags: database, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i have this model

```
class Social(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'social_auth_usersocialauth'
id = db.Column('id',db.Integer, primary_key=True)
provider = db.Column('provider',db.String(32))
extra_data = db.Column('extra_data',db.String())
uid = db.Column('uid',db.String(255))

def __init__(self,id=None, provider=None, extra_data=None, uid=None):
    self.id = id
    self.provider = provider
    self.extra_data = extra_data
    self.uid = uid
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Social %r>' % self.uid
```

then here is my function

```
test = Social.query.filter(Social.uid == current_user)
```

and when i get in on view like this {{ test }}

i get it's query, i want to get the result , how can i do this ?
here is the result on my view now:

```
SELECT social_auth_usersocialauth.id AS social_auth_usersocialauth_id, social_auth_usersocialauth.provider AS social_auth_usersocialauth_provider, social_auth_usersocialauth.extra_data AS social_auth_usersocialauth_extra_data, social_auth_usersocialauth.uid AS social_auth_usersocialauth_uid FROM social_auth_usersocialauth WHERE social_auth_usersocialauth.uid = :uid_1
```

Comment: that model is just a piece of it my model file :)

Comment: Don't you just need to add `.first()` to the end of your query?

Comment: i want to get all email that same with it, i use social auth , so a user can have more than 1 email in db,,, so i add .all()

Comment: i got this error also,,,
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'LocalProxy' [SQL: 'SELECT social_auth_usersocialauth.id AS social_auth_usersocialauth_id, social_auth_usersocialauth.provider AS social_auth_usersocialauth_provider, social_auth_usersocialauth.extra_data AS social_auth_usersocialauth_extra_data, social_auth_usersocialauth.uid AS social_auth_usersocialauth_uid \nFROM social_auth_usersocialauth \nWHERE social_auth_usersocialauth.uid = %(uid_1)s'] [parameters: {'uid_1': blablabla@blablabla.com}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. Let's start with the error.

In your query, you compare the `uid` field to the current user. Assuming `Social` is your user model, your query should include

```
Social.query.filter(Social.uid == current_user.uid)
```

Your other problem is how to access the results of your query. Methods like `filter` and `filter_by` return a `BaseQuery`(http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery). `BaseQuery` objects have several methods that expose the results depending on your needs. In this case it sounds like you want `all`(http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.all).

Putting this all together you get

```
test = Social.query.filter(Social.uid == current_user.uid).all()
```

Once in your template, you'll probably want to iterate over `test` rather than just echoing it directly.

```
{% for user in test %}
  {{ user }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you haven't defined `Social.__str__`, the output won't be very useful, but this should be enough to get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, dirn, it's so clear, hopefully my problem will be solved soon... :)

Comment: ouch, btw, i got this error
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'LocalProxy' [SQL: 'SELECT social_auth_usersocialauth.id AS social_auth_usersocialauth_id, social_auth_usersocialauth.provider AS social_auth_usersocialauth_provider, social_auth_usersocialauth.extra_data AS social_auth_usersocialauth_extra_data, social_auth_usersocialauth.uid AS social_auth_usersocialauth_uid \nFROM social_auth_usersocialauth \nWHERE social_auth_usersocialauth.uid = %(uid_1)s'] [parameters: {'uid_1': blablabla@blablabla.com}]

Comment: The first part of my answer addresses that. You can't compare a model instance to a string field. You need to compare a string (e.g., `Social.uid`) instead.

Comment: Hey, solved :)
in the end of my mode, i have this,
def __repr__(self):
        # return '<Social %r>' % self.uid
        return self.uid
so when i loop it, i just get uid, how can i get all data from it ? including other columns like provider, extra_data ? :)
Thank you.

Comment: If you want the repr to give you more than just uid, change it to give you more than just uid.

Comment: It's just code. Change it however you want. `return '<Social %r %r %r>' % (self.uid, self.provider, self.extra_data)`